# Onclick to parent element from child

Tags: onclick, parent

Have a problem.
How can I set parent element event "OnClick" from child window.
I try

```
newel.onclick = function() {document.forms.form_save_ent.submit();};
```

No working. Please help. Thanks

Full code

```
var parenttbl = window.opener.document.getElementById(\"row_panel\");
var newel = window.opener.document.createElement('td');
var elementid = document.getElementsByTagName(\"td\").length
newel.setAttribute('id',elementid);
newel.onclick = function() {document.forms.form_save_ent.submit();};
parenttbl.appendChild(newel);
```

Chrome write "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined"

Comment: Are you getting any error, or is the behavior different from what you expect?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please add some details: what error you are getting, for instance, and how you defined `newel`

Comment: The code you posted looks correct without seeing it in the context of the rest of the code. Please add additional details so we can try to recreate the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I get an error from the Chrome Developer mode. In most cases, he says that there is no such element